# Custom style stripe payment element layout

Tags: jquery, css, stripe-payments

Does anybody knows how we can customize the Stripe payment layout? My goal is to change layout like the first field should be full width and rest 3 should be aligned.

The style and iframe coming from stripe https://js.stripe.com/v3/

[image: Stripe grid-layout element style change]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can control when using the PaymentElement. With that integration, Stripe controls the UI and doesn't let you control the exact layout inside. You can control the parent's width/height and pass [various options](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api) for styling but none to control each field this way.

It's important to note that while your screenshot shows only card details, Stripe's PaymentElement is optimized for collecting payment method details across a wide range of payment method types. The amount of information to collect upfront differs on each one alongside the flow such as a full-page redirect to a partner versus a synchronous success or failure.

If you really want to control the layout itself and you only focus on card payments you could use a different integration where you create the element for each piece of information (number, expiration date and CVC) and display those on your page with your own layout. The fields are still controlled by Stripe to ease your PCI compliance cost. You can see docs about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/other_element?type=cardNumber).